# CABasicAnimation resets when edge swiping with UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, core-animation, cabasicanimation, caanimation

I have the following `CABasicAnimation` run in my `viewDidLoad` for a view controller inside a `UINavigationController`:

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
animation.duration = 1;
animation.additive = NO;
animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:-1*(((-windBearing+180) * M_PI) / 180)];
[compass.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"90rotation"];
```

When I use the edge swipe gesture to slowly navigate back, the animation resets to the initial state, which is quite jarring. I have my `fillMode` set and `removedOnCompletion` set to `NO`, what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This whole trick of setting the `fillMode` and the `removedOnCompletion` is nonsense - it's bad advice that has worked itself into a lot of answers, but it's totally wrong. The animation is one thing; the actual transform of the compass layer is another. You have applied the animation but you have forgotten to *set the `transform`* to match it. Therefore, when the gesture starts and the animation is removed from the layer, the compass is shown at its actual rotation (and the change appears as a jump).

Comment: " it's bad advice that has worked itself into a lot of answers, but it's totally wrong." +1000! If this were church, I'd say AMEN!

Comment: What does it mean? Where i need to set transform?

Comment: I think this answer would be better without the condescending first sentence.

Comment: @JohnGibb Fine by me, go ahead and take it out.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to matt above, I realized I was missing the following line:

```
compass.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-1*(((-windBearing+180) * M_PI) / 180));
```