# Animating CALayer vanishes when dragging on view controller to go back

Tags: ios, swift, cabasicanimation

I have an animating ring using CAShapeLayer and CABasicAnimation. The animation works fine however if I am using a navigation controller and drag on the screen to go back and then cancel the drag the layer that is animating vanishes. It reappears after the cancel and in the correct place:

[image: Timer]

[image: Timer on drag]

I am using `CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")`. Any ideas what might be causing this to happen? Any pointers would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CABasicAnimation resets when edge swiping with UINavigationController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33597503/cabasicanimation-resets-when-edge-swiping-with-uinavigationcontroller)